# How to use a Set data structure as a state in React Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, set

I want to initialize a React state as an empty Set in Typescript, and then add/remove values.

If I wanted to use an array, I would do this:

```
const [products, setProducts] = React.useState<String[]>([])

// And then to change it:

setProducts([...products, "new product"])
```

But I want to use a Set, so every value has to be unique. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Set is a mutable data structure, while the state should be immutable. When you need to update the state, first create a new Set off the old Set:

```
const next = new Set(prev) // prev is the old Set
```

Now you can update the new Set (`next`), and set it as the new state.

Initializing the state once using an [initializer function](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#parameters):

```
const [products, setProducts] = React.useState<String[]>(() => new Set())
```

Adding a value to the state:

```
setProducts(prev => {
  const next = new Set(prev) // create a new Set from the old one
  
  next.add(val) // add a value to the new Set

  return next
})
```

Removing a value from the state:

```
setProducts(prev => {
  const next = new Set(prev) // create a new Set from the old one

  next.delete(val) // remove a value from the new Set

  return next
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a Set object with the `useState` hook you can just do

```
const [products, setProducts] = React.useState(() => new Set());
```

***Please note***

React will not re-render if state is mutated i.e. if you do something like `products.add(something)` it will not trigger a re-render. In order to trigger a re-render you will have to call `setProducts` with a new `Set`. Depending on your requirements, a `Set` object may not be the best option!

Comment: You might want to include an example of how you would update the state then.

Comment: That was helpful, thanks. I'm aware of mutating states in React, I'm calling setState with a new set every time I update it. One question, what is the difference between calling new Set with an arrow function and not? I tried it without an arrow function and it also worked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just something simple like:

```js
let newProduct = 'new product';
setProducts(prev => (prev.includes(newProduct) ? [...products] : [...products, newProduct]));
```